column is returning an empty value in Azure devOps query

In the DevOps query results, the 'dev owner' column is returning an empty value even though it has data.

The Dev Owner is an Identity type custom field, right?

Yes @BrightRan-MSFT.

Try to turn on "New Boards Hubs". See my answer below for more details. @CroosNilukshan

It's not working yet.

How did you add the custom Identity type field "Dev Owner" to the Bug type item? Directly add it in the process or add it via an extension? @CroosNilukshan

What is the region of your Azure DevOps organization? You can go to "Organization Settings" > "Overview" page > "Region" section to get it. Try to check the query pages in your other organizations that are in different regions to see whether the same issue exists. @CroosNilukshan

Go to check if you have turned on "New Boards Hubs". If not, turn it on, then back to the query page.

I tested on my side, the Dev Owner column can display fine.


